# Do tag badges require strictly more than 100 (400, 1000) upvotes?

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-badges

I have had exactly 100 upvotes in [arrays](/questions/tagged/arrays) for a couple of days now, but I don't get the bronze bagde. When I was in a similar situation with 400 ups in [c](/questions/tagged/c), I got my badge shortly after my 401st upvote. So, is it that one requires not 100, 400, and 1000 ups but strictly more than that?

***Update:*** Thanks, all is resolved now :)

Comment: If it does, then the verbiage on the description is misleading and should be changed from "total score of [100|400|1000]" to "total score of more than [100|400|1000]", you appear to meet the only other criterion (min. number of answers)

Comment: There's also a requirement to have answered a minimum number of questions, which is clearly stated on the [relevant page](http://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags)

Comment: @ChrisF: Not true: I have 118 ups in only 33 questions in pointers tag, and I was awarded the badge anyway

Comment: @Armen that's because the minimum is 20 questions for the bronze badge.  @ChrisF as stated in my comment, he has met that criterion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We only update the denormalized tag totals (which tag badges pull from) once a day, and the badge in question also runs once a day, so you may see a delay in the badge being awarded.

I look at the data and you haven't yet had a score of 100 on answers in the [arrays](/questions/tagged/arrays) for a full day, the badge will be awarded tonight.

*Update:* In addition to the lag rules here, there was an actual problem with the job that started last night as well (result of another fix/optimization elsewhere).  It's been fixed and manually run just now, you'll now see the badge was awarded.

Comment: When you say "haven't had the score for a fully day" does that mean if there's a time period in which someone downvotes you (or removes an upvote) to make you dip below 100, and then undoes that action, that it would delay your badge?

Comment: @Daniel Dipping below would also remove your badge if you had it from previous - the tag badges actually require you to sustain your requirements, unlike other badges which do not get revoked. It happens barely frequently, though, and it's generally pretty easy to recuperate the votes.

Comment: What reported by @Grace Note is (indeed) correct. The badge for creating a tag used by 50 questions is kept, even when the tag doesn't exist anymore; the badges obtained for having a score of at least 100 on X questions tagged with a specific tag are removed once the score is lower than 100.

Comment: @Nick: See my edit

Comment: @Armen - will check on the job in just a few min, it's possible something is off here - will update soon as I've found the issue.

Comment: @Armen - See above, there was an issue, resolved now.

Answer (score 3):

You should get it once you get a score of 100 on answers tagged [arrays](/questions/tagged/arrays) that are not CW. The badge is not immediately assigned in the moment you get a score of 100, but the code that assign such badges is run at a specific moment of the day.

Comment: But I have had 100 nonCW ups for arrays tag for at least 2 days now. How do you explain that? The same happened with the c badge